# How to instantiate Angular components with parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-components

I've been trying to instantiate components by passing parameters like `nameFilter = new FilterComponent("Name");` but I'm getting this error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for String!

I believe dependency injection causes this as I don't get any errors if I don't inject anything to component. So what exactly causes this and how can I fix it?

Here's the component code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-filter',
     templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./filter.component.scss']
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
     title: String;

     constructor(title: String) {
          this.title = title;
     }

     ngOnInit() {
     }
}
```

Comment: In constructor param you refer title of type ``String`` replace it with ``string`` ,s in lower case

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: Changing it to `string` will also not work since Angular will try to find a provider for `string` which is a primitive type. Also as good design, avoid injecting primitive types in constructors.

Comment: I've been trying to create multiple instances of a component class with different values, which is why I did this. Honestly, I don't know how to do it without injecting primitive values. Could you explain how?

Comment: you are looking for @Input that you will inject from html where you call your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear and you're right, the dependency injection mechanism is causing it. Every dependency you pass into the constructor must be injected at run-time and Angular needs to know what to pass in.

In your case, Angular does not know what to inject as the string `title`.

You can explicitly tell Angular what to inject in your module provider array for String type. However, this means that whatever you provide in the providers array will be used every time.

```
@NgComponent({
    ...
    providers: [
    { provide: String, useValue: 'my title' }
  ],
})
```

Having looked at your code, you can initialise the component with an `@Input` variable - [Angular component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input() title: string; 
}

<app-filter [title]="Title 1"></app-filter>
```

Simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs6sfy

Comment: Injecting values from HTML might indeed be the better solution but I can't seem to get it to work for some reason. The title value becomes undefined when I try your second code snippet.

Comment: Oh, it was the " " all along. It should have been ' '.

Answer (score 3):

As a good design practice, **avoid** injecting primitive data types like `string`, `number`, `date` etc in component constructors.

But if you still need to inject them. Then you should let Angular know about the token and the value which is going to be injected.

For this Angular provides the `InjectionToken` API. https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#injectiontoken

Example for injecting a date type in a component:

```js
export const DATE = new InjectionToken<Date>('date');

@NgComponent({
    ...
    providers: [
    { provide: DATE, useValue: new Date() } //can be declared at the module as well
  ],
})
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(DATE) private fromDate: Date,
    @Inject(DATE) private toDate: Date
  ) {}

}
```